# How can I set up my app to receive requests from another script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tried testing the app by sending requests through Postman, but I get a login webpage as a response. I enabled "Access by anyone, even anonymous" when deploying the app, so I wouldn't that that a user needs to log in to trigger the webhook.

I want to be able to run my script just by sending a POST request with some data from a raspberry pi python script.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log('I got a GET request');

  spreadsheet.appendRow(['test1', 'test2', '', 'test4']);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
}


function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log('Got a POST.');
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success');
}
```

Comment: Are you using a `doPost(e)` function inside of the Apps Script project?

Comment: Yes. I have a doGet(e) and doPost(e). doGet() works if I try in my browser, I assume because I'm logged in. But from Postman I get a login page as a response. I added my code to the original post.

Comment: Are you using the URL with 'exec' on the end?  There are two URL's, one for development, and one for public use.

Comment: Well, something doesn't make any sense here.  If the code is published to run as "Me", and "anyone, even anonymous", then no log in is required.  Obviously something is wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.  When this happens to me, I start at the beginning and first get the simplest code to run, and build from there.  Your `doPost(e)` code is wrong.  But it seems that you refuse to fix it, assuming that it's not going to make any difference.  I start with what is obviously wrong, whether I think it is related or not.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out I was using the /dev URL. I added the answer to my question. I didn't notice there were two URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Sandy Good.

I have found out that I was using the wrong URL the entire time, ending with /dev. I never realized there were two URLs, and after switching from /dev to the /exec URL, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a change to the code, you must constantly publish a new version.  Even the slightest change, you must publish a new version and make sure that you are using the version with "exec" on the end.

You have:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
```

Which does not technically create content.  It creates something like an HtmlService object.  I'm not sure what the exact official term is, but in any case, you need to "chain" `.getContent()` to the end:

```
h = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>').getContent();
```

That returns a string.  You might be able to return that.  If not, try using Content Service.

Might also try:

```
var c,h;
h = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>').getContent();

c = ContentService.createTextOutput(h);
return c;
```

Comment: Whether or not the response is correct or not, the log statement and spreadsheet lines before the response fail to run when receiving requests from Postman. It doesn't trigger the code because it's not logged in.